# Handling numerical lists in php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, list

I'm writing a small list system which is ordered via a numerical field in the database that is dynamic

The database holds the following:

```
Id | position | person 
======================
1  | 3        | John 
2  | 1        | Jane
3  | 4        | David
4  | 2        | Emily
```

Now when I select that list I sort it via the position field.
What I want to do is manage this order via a backend and whilst I have the main principle down, one thing that I am struggling with is the situation where a someone updates say Emily to 3 without changing the others in that ordered list.

So the page that updates the order just has the persons name and a text box with the current order in it.

I want to try to work out a way to handle this but can't seem to grasp any possible way to do this as all will be saved at once so there is no way to determine which item has changed, and therefore should be the correct one in case of duplicate.

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing to note is that the "post" data from the form will get a raw dump of data of all numerical positions do simply re-ordering Wong really work because how will it know what has changed without first requesting the database.  I can of course do that which would work but it seems far from elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just sort like this:

```
...order by position, person
```

That way, people with the same 'position' will still be ordered reliably (by name). Leave the "fixing" up to the user.

Ofcourse, the best way to handle this would be to not bother the user at all with a 'position' field but use a [draggable sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/sortable.html) list of some kind.

Comment: Unfortunately other display logic and requirements depend heavily on the numbers rather than name.

Comment: I disagree slightly. Since you could get into a position where everyone has the same position so moving people would never change the order as it would default to the persons name for ordering. The draggable sort is a good interface, but the backend still needs to save the new positions, otherwise the list order would reset every time its displayed/used.

Comment: But I like the idea of a draggable list I might look at that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move Emily DOWN the list her position 2 become 3.
So you need to move 3 back up to 2 (which was Emilys position)

The same goes for moving UP the list. You are basically swapping positions of the next/previous record. BUT you need to check that there is a record to swap with.

PSEUDO CODE MOVE DOWN:

1. get Emily
2. update record below Emily (Emily's position+1)
3. IF updated okay - update Emily position

Answer (score 0):

One logic behind reordering a list manually would be to reorder the entire relevant list items whenever one list position is changed. Changing 10 to 2 would require everything from 2 to 9 to be pushed +1 position forward, so the logic would be

```
for i in new pos+1..old pos
    pos[i]++
```

Comment: OR: UPDATE table SET position=position+1 WHERE position BETWEEN 2 AND 10 AND id!=4

Comment: Yes! How did I not think of that

Answer (score 0):

here is an exemple that i use
first i change the position of the row, lets use `calendar_event_id = 7` as exemple , and then i call reposition, that runs:

```
SET @position = 0;
UPDATE calendar_events SET position = @position := @position + 1 
WHERE position >= 0 
ORDER BY position, IF(calendar_event_id = 7, 0, 1), name
```

and if you deleted a row, just skip the `IF(calendar_event_id = 7, 0, 1),` part